# Installing MySQL on a mac

Tags: mysql, macos

i have downloaded and installed `mySQL` my double clicking on its icon. It was installed successfully.

When i goto startup and preference i see the icon of mysql added and when i click on it i see a screen where it says 'MySQL server instance is running'.

But when i open terminal and `cd` to `/usr/local/mysql` and then when i type `sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe` i was prompted for a password. and i have not added a password when i installed mySQL, so i tried leaving it blank, and then i tried various passwords to login but all attempts failed.

So now i need to know how to login to mySQL via the terminal ?

mysql version - 5.5.24-osx10.6x86_64
my Mac OS - 10.7.3

Comment: mysqld_safe is the command to start the mysql service, which you say is already running.  To start the client just use the 'mysql' command.

Comment: it says `-bash: mysql: command not found` when i type mysql in the terminal

Comment: If you type `sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe` it asks you for the super-user password. Have you tried to type your admin passord ?

Comment: once i typed mysqld_safe it prompts for a password. and i didn't enter a password while intalling mySQL. so how can i enter a password here ?

Comment: @Olwaro admin password means, the password of my machine ? I have not added a password to my machine. and it doesn't allow to keep the password field blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found installing mysql on MacOs, there are a few differences.  One is that it installs it without a password.  The other thing is that it by default allows for anonymous logins.

Use this to set the password:

```
mysqladmin -u root -h localhost password yourpassword
```

You can remove anonymous logins this way:

```
shell> mysql -u root -p
Enter password: (enter root password here)
mysql> DROP USER ''@'localhost';
mysql> DROP USER ''@'host_name';
```

The other thing is that I found that the install does not modify the path variable.  What I did to run mysql from the command line was to add /usr/local/mysql/bin to path by adding it to /etc/paths or /etc/paths.d .   This may be what you need in order to run mysql.  Like someone said in the comments, mysqld_safe is one way to start the mysql server, and it seems that is already set to run.

Here are specific instructions to add something to /etc/paths.d

```
$ cd /etc/paths.d
$ cat > mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysql
```

(and then type Ctrl-D
that should put a file there)

you may have to sudo if you do not have permissions.

Comment: it says `-bash: mysqladmin: command not found` not found when i type `mysqladmin -u root -h localhost password yourpassword
`

Comment: How do i add ` /usr/local/mysql/bin to path by adding it to /etc/paths or /etc/paths.d ` ? how can i open paths.d ?

Comment: Try the last thing I said, adding /usr/loca/mysql/bin (assuming that's where it installed) to /etc/paths or /etc/paths.d  (look up how to set paths like that, not in a .bash_rc or something).  Then you should be able to run it in a new terminal window.

Comment: check out http://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x for how to set global path values on MacOs.  The first answer is useful.  You may have to sudo for this, I'm not sure, depending on your permissions

Comment: Yes i went through that, when i type `ls /etc/paths.d` i see only `x11`. So how can i write the command thereafter to add mysql to the PATH ?

Comment: Yes, there may be just X11.  What you need to do is put a file in that directory, call it "mysql" and in the file, it should say /usr/local/mysql/bin (or wherever your mysql is installed).  Then when you open new terminals, it should apply to the path.

Comment: can you show me the exact commands to add this path to that folder. I need to know how to create the file and then add the path, and finally to display the path with echo $PATH

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11707/discussion-between-titania424-and-sharon-hwk)

Answer (score 1):

The sudo command, by default, lets anyone in the admin group run a command as root by giving his own password. That's why it asked for your password when you typed "sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe". It has nothing whatsoever to do with mysql.

If you don't have a password, you cannot use sudo in the default configuration. Either give yourself a password, or edit the sudoers file. (I would strongly suggest the former over the latter, especially if you have no idea what sudo does.)

For more information, type "man sudo" (and then "man sudoers") from your Terminal.

Meanwhile, the reason "it says -bash: mysql: command not found when i type mysql in the terminal" is because you've clearly installed it into /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql, and that isn't on your path. If it were on your path, you could have just done "sudo mysqld_safe" above, instead of "sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe". Since it's not, you have to do "./bin/mysqld_safe".

For more information, consult a good primer on the Unix shell.

Finally, if you've got the mysql daemon running, and are trying to start the client, it's "mysql" that you want to run, not "mysqld_safe".